# How to append path+file for glob.glob

Tags: python, glob, simpleitk

I have code as follows, it gives me a SimpleITK error

```
"ERROR: The file in the series have unsupported 3 dimensions."
```

The result of print path is

```
['C:/DataLuna16pred\\subset0\\1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.6279.6001.100225287222365663678666836860.mhd'];
```

How to use it correctly ?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("C:/DataLuna16pred/CSVFILES/candidates89.csv")
for idx in df.index:
    seriesuid=df.seriesuid[idx]
    path= 'C:/DataLuna16pred/*/'
    path = glob.glob(path+seriesuid+'.mhd')
    ds = sitk.ReadImage(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two signatures of `sitk.ReadImage` the first is an interface to the sitk.ImageFileReader which takes a single string for a file name. That is for reading a single image.

The second one you invoked by passing a list, is to the sitk.ImageSeriesReader which takes an array or list of file names to join the images together into a volume. This version only takes a list of 2D images to form a 3D image. Your argument `path` is a python list.

It is not clear to me what your intentions are with the glob. Is it to get one file name? or multiple?

You may need to check the `len(path)` and if it is one pass path[0] to `sitk.ReadImage`

Comment: Got it ! Try  "ds = sitk.ReadImage(path[0])" and it work . Thanks a lot ~